# How can I select distinct values into a pivot using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Pandas question:
If I have this dataframe:

| Member | Value | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | AC |
| 1 | c | AC |
| 1 | d | DF |
| 2 | b | AC |
| 2 | e | DF |

which I would like to transform, using pivot?, to a DataFrame showing occurences of individual elements of the group, like:

| x | AC | DF |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ac | d |
| 2 | b | e |

I run into "Index contains duplicate values, cannot reshape" if I try:
`pivot(index='Member', columns=['Group'], values='Value')`

Feel confused over something seemingly very trivial. Can somebody help?

Comment: Check `pivot_table`

Comment: Use `df.pivot_table('Value', 'Member', 'Group', aggfunc=''.join)`

Comment: thx

I was struggling myself with agg(['unique']) which seems to lead somewhere too.

Comment: then change `aggfunc=''.join` - `aggfunc= lambda x: ''.join(x.unique())`